# AngularJs doesn't want to return defer.promise

Tags: angularjs, deferred

This is my view (Sorry for the long variable and functions names):

```
   <tr  ng-repeat="passation in passations " >
<td ng-init=" passation.stats_quota_campagnes = get_stats_quota_campagnes(passation)">{{passation.stats_quota_campagnes}}</div></td>
</tr>
```

This is my angularjs function who is supposed to return the result :

```
$scope.get_stats_quota_campagnes = function(passation){

     var defer = $q.defer();
    $http.post('backend/backend.php?action=stats_quota_campagnes',{'id_passation':passation.id_passation})
    .success(function(data){ 
        console.log(data);

          defer.resolve(data);

    });
      return defer.promise;
}
```

The console.log(data); show this, 'im getting correct data from the PHP back end :

```
Object { 0: "401", Quota: "401" }
```

But i've tried plenty of things, but totally unable to get the Quota value into my view ! The defer.promise variable is always empty  I don't understand why. What could i do please ?

On my view, isee this actually :

```
{}
```

instead of the value , while the console.log shows that it is working, the right variables are coming from the $http, but the view doesn't update. I've heard about $apply(), but don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to do anything with your promise, just assign the data to your variable in the `.then` callback:

```
$scope.get_stats_quota_campagnes = function(passation){

    $http.post('backend/backend.php?action=stats_quota_campagnes',{'id_passation':passation.id_passation})
        .success(function(data){ 
            console.log(data);
            passation.stats_quota_campagnes = data;
        });
}
```

And in your view:

```
<tr ng-repeat="passation in passations">
    <td ng-init="get_stats_quota_campagnes(passation)">
        {{passation.stats_quota_campagnes}}
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: How do i know the variable name because its an ng-repeat, the function need to be called for each objects of the ng-repeat

Comment: @nick You just call the scope function with your `passation` as parameter. In the `.success` callback angular puts the retrieved data on your `passation` object, so in your view you can use `passation.stats_quota_campagnes `

Comment: $scope.myVariableUsedInView can't exist because it is a ng-repeat loop, i have several passation variables who need to be updated during the ng-repeat. I can't see how to use $scope.myVariableUsedInView = data

Comment: I already edited my answer, use `passation.stats_quota_campagnes`, because in the `.success` callback I set the `passation.stats_quota_campagnes = data;`

Comment: Ok, it is working, thank you a lot, i find it strange that we can't return the value, and that we must assign it.

Comment: Working very very well !

Comment: That is because the `$http` itself doesn't return a value, but a promise. That promise on its turn can be used to resolve the value.

Answer (score 0):

You can aacces resolved promise value only inside `then` callback:

```
somePromise.then(function(value) {
    console.log(value)
})
```

In your case you can do something like this:

```
$scope.get_stats_quota_campagnes = function(passation){

    var defer = $q.defer();
    $http.post('backend/backend.php?action=stats_quota_campagnes',{'id_passation':passation.id_passation})
    .success(function(data){ 
        console.log(data);
        $scope.data = data;
    });
}
```

And then you can access `$scope.data` in your template

Comment: I have several passation objects in my ng-repeat that needs to be updated by calling the function, ive tried that but can't get any value on each passation objects of the ng-repeat

Comment: You can iterate over your `passations` collection in controller and call `get_stats_quota_campagne`  passing `passation` item as an argument. You don't have to do this in template

Answer (score 0):

This is not how it works. If you want to init the `passation.stats_quota_campagnes` scope you have to call the service in controller and then assign the result to the scope.

e.g.

```
angular.module('app')

    .controller('myController', ['$scope', 'myService', function ($scope, myService) {
        //...some other code in your controller.

        $scope.passation.stats_quota_campagnes  = [];

        $scope.get_stats_quota_campagnes = function (passation, index) {
            myService(passation).then(successCallback, failCallback);

            function successCallback(response) {
                $scope.passation[index].stats_quota_campagnes = response;
            };

            function failCallback(response) {
                //Do whatever you have to do.
            }
        };


        //This requires you have passation array initialized.
        angular.forEach(passation, function(val,index) {
            $scope.get_stats_quota_campagnes(val,index);
        });

    }])

    .service('myService', ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {
        return function (passation) {

            var defer = $q.defer();
            $http.post('backend/backend.php?action=stats_quota_campagnes', {
                    'id_passation': passation.id_passation
                })
                .success(function (data) {
                    console.log(data);

                    defer.resolve(data);

                });
            return defer.promise;
        }

    }])
```

Then in the view

```
<tr  ng-repeat="passation in passations" >
    <td>{{passation.stats_quota_campagnes}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, i Will try this too